# Proper way to write logs and data somewhere

Tags: c#, windows

We have a windows application, that can be either installed in program files or copied and used from somewhere else. Futhermore the customer often wants to use several versions of application from the same machine (long story short: customer has N projects, each in a different stage so each require different version of our application. Customer base it's own projects on top of our application/framework).

We started to see complaints from the customers that running our application requries admin permissions because:

- We write text logs to local folder. We use windows events as logs as well, but text logs are requirement.
- We write DB cache to local folder. DB cache should persist between app runs as much as possible.
- We also write some other files, like firmware that are needed only in app run lifetime and can be deleted when application closes.

We decided that we should do something about that. Probably we should write all this stuff to `%AppData%/[someFolder]`. The issue is that customer may have several different instances of our app, and they should have separate logs/cache. Customer even may have the same version installed twice, so we cannot use version as a key.

Current idea is to use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` as key, so the path to write will be something like `$"%AppData%\{Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)}"`. This will probably work, but looks very weird and hacky.

Is there any better way to manage this? I'm also thinking of issueing each app instance a GUID and using it instead, but I'm not sure how to do that properly.

Comment: You may be over complicating things. Is there something that you cannot create logs in executable location, or in some folder called "logs", "db" etc. next to exe? There is also C:\Windows\Temp folder for temporary files that only needed while application is running. And if you wish use AppData. Create small file with UID of this current application and create folder in app data using this UID

Comment: Why not just let the customer choose where to write this data? Give them a config option, let them deal with the permissions.

Comment: @Sinatr We have an installer but some customers prefer to copy application, so we support that as well. Still the normal way for the customer is to run an instaler, install into Program Files and use it from there. Unfortunately this means that we cannot write logs there, as this is restricted location. Asking customer every time to run it as admin or handling UAC is not an option

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak We cannot write logs to local folder if it is installed under Program Files, because it is restricted location (UAC complains). Using UID may be an option, it's better than generating GUID. The downside of this is having a hard time figuring out where your logs are, when you have 5+ app instances installed

Comment: @DavidG It's a good idea to add a config option for that, and we will probably do it. But I'd like to have a default option viable if possible

Comment: Default option could be to write to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\AppName\\Logs"`

Comment: @Sinatr Using `C:\Company Name\Software Name` might work, but unfortunately having app in Program Files by default was a requirement up until now. This means I need to bring conversation up, which I will do, but I'd like to know that this is the only good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to `c:\Program Files` or to `C:\Company Name` are both no good ideas and conflictwith Windows best practices. Writing to program files requires admin permissions for a reason! Writing to `C:\Company Name` is possible, but only for backward compatibility reasons and is totally out of date.
My proposal is to write to `Appdata`, whether it is `.\Local`, `.\LocalLow` or `.\Roaming` is your choice, but there are best practices ([read this post](https://superuser.com/questions/21458/why-are-there-directories-called-local-locallow-and-roaming-under-users-user))
You can also use `%Programdata%\YourFolderName`.

In order to keep instances of your program separate of each other: Take the either process ID (these are unique at any given time, but not over time), or use a random number. A GUID is one example of a random number (or random string), but if a GUID seems to ugly to you, a 4 byte (`long`) random number will also do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I decide to put my comments into the answer as they are already result of thoughts of some people (which you seems are about to do).

**Relative folders** are way easier solution if you have multiple versions of software installed at the same time, then you shouldn't have conflicts (assuming they all have different base folder) or confusion of *which witch is which*.

```
C:\Company Name\Software Name 1.0
C:\Company Name\Software Name 1.1
C:\Company Name\Software Name 2.1
D:\Test\Blablabla
```

It will be very easy to find software executables and corresponding data. I personally dislike `AppData` idea (as both: developer and user) mainly for confusion it introduces, because software `A` may suddenly store its data in

```
c:\Users\Current User\AppData\LocalOrLocalLowOrRoamingTryToGuessWhich\SomeWeirdFolderNameToExampleB
```

Typically it's an installer work to check for windows version, check folders rights, etc. to ensure that application will have correct environment, but software can do it as well on startup to at least give warning whenever conditions to successfully run aren't met.

In our company software installer by default offers `C:\Company Name\Software Name Version` folder and that's ok for our customers.

If you must use `Program Files` (because, well, this is not bad), then e.g. [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/) client will do something to make its folder inside `Program Files` writable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've discussed this with our IT, and they insisted we should use `%ProgramData%`. They've seen a lot of permission problems on Windows 10, with both `C:\Company Name` and `%ProgramFiles%`. Looks like in Windows 10 this became even worse than it was before. I think our approach will be either to use `GUID`, or maybe `DbName` + `Version` under `%ProgramData%`. We are still thinking between those two options